# Distributing candies to three children

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Grandma Sue has $8$ distinct candies to distribute amongst her $3$ distinct children, how many ways can this be done in if each child is to get at least $2$ candies.

My attempt:

Choose $6$ out of $8$ candies in $\binom{8}{6}$ ways, distribute these $6$ amongst the three by giving two to each child in $\frac{6!}{(2!)^3}$ ways and finally distribute the remaining two chocolates in $3^2$ ways.

The correct answer given is $2940$ and my above analysis gives $22680$.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach seems right at a glance.
But there is one problem. It distinguishes the first two candies and the additional ones.

Case $1$. Child A gets candy $1$ & $2$ when you distribute two candies for each child. And then A gets additional candy $7$.

Case $2$. Child A gets candy $1$ & $7$ when you distribute two candies for each child. And then A gets additional candy $2$.

These two cases should be considered as the same case(A gets candies $1$, $2$, $7$) but your approach distinguished these two cases.

Solution: only possible distribution is (4,2,2) or (3,3,2)

$(4,2,2)$ case : ${8}\choose{4}$${4}\choose{2}$${2}\choose{2}$$\times 3 = 1260$.
You choose $4$ out of $8$ and  choose $2$ out of $4$ and choose a child who will get $4$ candies.

$(3,3,2)$ case : $8\choose 3$$5 \choose 3$$2\choose 2$$\times 3 = 1680$

1260+1680 = 2940

Comment: Thanks a lot, i get it now